# Optimize the query in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the below query which I am using to find the single and split transactions for each of the classes.

First I created a table with class1 skus from the master sku table and then I created 9 more tables for the rest of the 9 classes. I have to run the below query for each class..Is there a better way to run one query for all the classes at once?

```
SELECT v.transaction_type
     , COUNT(DISTINCT v.transaction_number) AS transaction_count
     , COUNT(DISTINCT v.individual_id) AS customer_count
     , SUM(v.quantity) AS units
     , SUM(v.dollar_value_us) AS sales
     , SUM(v.dollar_value_us - v.cogs * v.quantity) AS profit
  FROM (SELECT td.transaction_number, td.sku, td.quantity, td.dollar_value_us, td.individual_id, td.cogs,
               CASE 
                 WHEN COUNT(ps.sku) OVER (PARTITION BY td.transaction_number) > 0
                 THEN 'Yes'
                 ELSE 'No'
               END AS has_pod_sku,
               CASE  
                 WHEN COUNT(ps.sku) OVER (PARTITION BY td.transaction_number) > 0
                  AND COUNT(ps.sku) OVER (PARTITION BY td.transaction_number)
                    < COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY td.transaction_number)
                 THEN 'Split'
                 ELSE 'Single'
               END AS transaction_type
          FROM dm_owner.transaction td
          LEFT OUTER
          JOIN class1 ps on ps.sku = td.sku
          
          where TD.brand_org_code = 'brand'
and is_merch = 1
and line_item_amt_type_cd = 'S' 

and trunc(TXN_DATE) between '01-JAN-19' AND '31-DEC-19' 
     ) v
 WHERE has_pod_sku = 'Yes'
 GROUP BY v.transaction_type
```

This is the sample database which I have created:

[link]https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=07e5283cb4c06e4260ff266ff5d36f1a

Comment: Sample data and the output you're trying to get from that data would be helpful.

Comment: this is the sample database @KenWhite https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=07e5283cb4c06e4260ff266ff5d36f1a

Comment: From the db fiddle link you have already got the answer you are looking for. IIUC, you wish to run this on a per aggregate basis of the class. So you would in both the partition by clauses, include the class_no and also in the final group by you would have a class_no

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph, if I add the class_no in the partition by clauses then it messes up with the transaction type :(

Comment: i suggest you provide a tiny, complete set of data in the dbfiddle link you have. That way we would know what causes the changes